# UTF-8 Character encoding Issues with smarty templates

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I am storing a registered trademark symbol with a product name in a mysql table. The table is utf8 unicode. When I render the page using Smarty templates I see `ProductÂ®` when I should be seeing `Product®`.

After stepping through I can see the right before the template is rendered the variable looks like `Product®` but after render it adds the strange `Â` character.  I also tested this by using the php `utf8_encode()` and can visibly see the character being added after the encoding.

How do I strip this character and render so it isn't shown. I've tried something like this:

```
        $product= str_replace('®', '&reg;', $product);
        $product= html_entity_decode($product);
```

But still see the strange `Â` character show up in the product name. I have seen different issues on SO regarding a similar character but now solutions as to how to deal with it.

Comment: Can you try this in your HTML head <meta charset="UTF-8">

Comment: I'm gonna hazard a guess that the answer lies [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through/279279)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like "Mojibake", where `®` becomes `Â®`.

This discusses the various causes for such:  [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)